# Why I cant update cells of a row in DataTable using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to update 3 cells of a single row after Ajax success but it doesn't work, it just doesn't make the update. The data are correctly received in Ajax success however the table does not get populated with the new data. I tried it like this:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

table.cell({
   row: 1,
   column: 1
}).data("value 1").draw();

table.cell({
   row: 1,
   column: 2
}).data("value 2").draw();

table.cell({
   row: 1,
   column: 3
}).data("value 3").draw();
```

According to the documentation this is the way to update a single cell, so why is it not working in my case? Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT. Below you can see all the jQuery scripts I am importing:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Bear in mind a couple of points: (A) The row and column indexes are zero-based, so "row 1 column 2" means the third cell in the second row. And (B) by default, a table is sorted on the first column (index zero!). So, what you see displayed may not be row index 1 - that original row  (row index 1) may have been sorted to some other location in the displayed (sorted) data. Search for the word "value" - maybe you will find your data.

Comment: @andrewjames I only have 3 rows so I would see if any changes are made. I am already sorting and I do know that the row count starts from 0. Still, I dont understand why its not working. Could it be the jQuery scripts I am using?

Comment: @andrewjames found a mistake I was doing, fixed that but still I cannot update the cells

Comment: You have some duplicated scripts (two jquery JS, and two DataTables JS) - but even with your imports, the updates still work for me.

Comment: @andrewjames fixed it, I was suppose to define table inside the JS function and not as I was doing globally.

Comment: @andrewjames maybe you could help me solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270876/how-to-create-a-button-that-calls-a-function-and-passes-parameters-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment111885527_63270876